# Is it safe to use an input field in an audio player?

Tags: javascript, audio

I have an audio player I'm making for my website and need to know if it's safe to use `<input>` for volume control and as a progress bar?

I know that `<input>` fields can be used as man-in-the-middle attacks and want to know if it's safe to use them. This is mainly to do volume control and to move the position of an audio file.

Another option I was looking into was using JavaScript to turn a 'div' into an 'input' function. Is that method safer or less secure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing about front end development is that anyone can change the front end. For example, if you open up chrome dev tools and change a div tag into an input tag, then the browser will happily display what was previously a div tag as an input tag. The security holes start appearing when I can send some malicious input to your backend and change what gets loaded on other people's browsers.

In short, no, turning a div into an input is not any more or less secure. What you do with that input on the backend however is another matter.